# How to print random CSV text entry that meets a specific criteria?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to develop a python program that generates a random interview question for a specific medical school selected by the user. I have a csv. file where column 0 has the university name, and column 1 has an interview question. I am not sure on how to develop a code that randomly outputs an interview question only from a specific medical school.

For example: If the user selects 'Baylor College of Medicine', I would like to randomly print one question (located in column 1) that has 'Baylor College of Medicine' in column 0.

Here is my attempted code at the moment:

```
import random
import pandas as pd

csv_file = "question_data.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, names=["College", "Question"])
modified_df = df.dropna()
df_question = modified_df.groupby("College")["Question"]

def generateRandomQuestion():
    for College, frame in df_question:
        print(f"Here is a question from {College!r}")
        print(frame.sample(n=1, random_state=2))

generateRandomQuestion()
```

Here is a sample of the csv:

```
Baylor College of Medicine,What scares you in medicine?
Baylor College of Medicine,What do you think is the biggest problem in today's healthcare?
Baylor College of Medicine,What do you like to do for fun?
Baylor College of Medicine,What are your thoughts on healthcare?
Columbia University College of Physicians and Surgeons,Where do you see yourself as a physician in 20-25 years?
Columbia University College of Physicians and Surgeons,What was your favorite class in undergrad?
Columbia University College of Physicians and Surgeons,What's your family like?
Columbia University College of Physicians and Surgeons,What did you think of your school?
```

Any help would be incredibly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use any `.groupby()` construct here, and I think that was where you were getting stuck.

Your function should accept arguments, and it can be very simple like this:

```
def generateRandomQuestion(df,college): 
    return random.choice(df[df['College'] == college]['Question'].values)
```

You can get user input for the college name, and then call the above function like this:

```
college = input('Please enter the name of a college: ')

random_question = generateRandomQuestion(modified_df,college) 

print(random_question)
```